# XAML - Customize items of a custom combobox

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I have the following code:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxControlTemplate" TargetType="ComboBoxe">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox 
                        x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" 
                        Template="{StaticResource TextBoxBaseControlTemplate}" 
                        FontSize="25" 
                        FontFamily="{StaticResource CommonFont}" 
                        FontWeight="Light"
                        TextChanged="EmployeeField_TextChanged"
                        GotFocus="EmployeeField_OnGotFocus"
                        LostFocus="EmployeeField_OnLostFocus"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

                    <Popup 
                        Name="Popup"
                        Placement="Bottom"
                        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                        AllowsTransparency="True" 
                        Focusable="False"
                        PopupAnimation="Slide">

                        <StackPanel Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" IsItemsHost="True" Background="#FFEEEEEE" />
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

There's a slight problem, though.  The `StackPanel` containing the actual items of the `ComboBox` displays each item with padding or some sort of margin around it.  I have a separate `DataTemplate` for the `ComboBox` items, which includes a border underneath each item.  But since there's the aforementioned padding or whatever, the border doesn't extend all the way across the `Popup`.  I need a border that extends the entire way across.
Additionally, I need to be able to specify the color and border that is displayed when the user mouses over the items.

Comment: Have you tried a custom ComboBoxItem style? Just set the ItemContainerStyle property on the ComboBox with a custom style, and check if the margin is in the item itself.

Comment: It took a little bit of fiddling around with it, but I got that to work.  Thanks!